# Cards inside the grid-container: each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I`m doing wrong?It also says: "Check the render method of `Card`" , which is here:

```
<div className="grid-container">
   {pokemonData.map((pokemon, i) => {
      console.log(pokemon.id) // unique numbers are here
      return <Card key={pokemon.id} pokemon={pokemon} />
     })}
 </div>
```

Card component itself:

```
function Card({ pokemon }) {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card__image">
                <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt="Pokemon" />
            </div>
            <div className="card__name">
                {pokemon.name}
            </div>
            <div className="card__types">
                {
                    pokemon.types.map(type => {
                        return (
                            <div className="card__type" style={{backgroundColor: typeColors[type.type.name]}}>
                                {type.type.name}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
            <div className="card__info">
                <div className="card__data card__data--weight">
                    <p className="title">Weight:</p>
                    <p>{pokemon.weight}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="card__data card__data--height">
                    <p className="title">Height:</p>
                    <p>{pokemon.height}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="card__data card__data--ability">
                    <p className="title">Abilities:</p>
                    {/* {console.log(pokemon.abilities)} Temporary for dev puprose */}
                    {pokemon.abilities.map(ability => <p>{ability.ability.name}</p>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Please add code for the Card component. How you are using key prop in the card component?

Comment: Please add the error also in the question.

Comment: @AlphaOne done. Actually, I`m not using it, where I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index of the array may be your data is having some kind of duplicate. It is recommended that you pass a `key prop` whenever you are returning a list.

```
<div className="grid-container">
   {pokemonData.map((pokemon, i) => {
      console.log(pokemon.id) // unique numbers are here
      return <Card key={i} pokemon={pokemon} />
     })}
 </div>
```

Equally, check this segment of card components.

```
{
  pokemon.types.map((type,i) => {
  return (
       <div key={i} className="card__type" style={{backgroundColor: 
               typeColors[type.type.name]}}>
               {type.type.name}
        /div>
         )
     })
 }
```

And

```
<div className="card__data card__data--ability">
      <p className="title">Abilities:</p>
      {/* {console.log(pokemon.abilities)} }
     {pokemon.abilities.map((ability, i) => <p key={i}>{ability.ability.name} 
      </p>
      )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer will solve your problem. However, for your info, I would also like to add here.

For React a key attribute is like an identity of a node/element/tag which helps React to identify each item in the list and apply reconciliation correctlyon each item. Without a key React will render your component but may cause issue when you re-order your list.

React recommends to use id of the data instead of index number. However, if your list does not re-orders/ sorts or do not have id then you can use index.

You can read more here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<div className="card__types">
   {
      pokemon.types.map(type => {
        return (
               <div className="card__type" 
                style={{backgroundColor:typeColors[type.type.name]}}
               >
                 {type.type.name}
               </div>
               )
      })
    }
</div>
```

to:

```
<div className="card__types">
   {
      pokemon.types.map((type, key) => {
        return (
               <div key={key} className="card__type" 
                style={{backgroundColor:typeColors[type.type.name]}}
               >
                 {type.type.name}
               </div>
               )
      })
    }
</div>
```

and:

```
{pokemon.abilities.map(ability => <p>{ability.ability.name}</p>
```

to:

```
{pokemon.abilities.map((ability,key) => <p key={key} >{ability.ability.name}</p>
```